# How to read in a game board from a text file and convert it to a 2D array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, text-files

An example of the board I would have to read from is something like this:

[image: Example Board in text file]

Now, the "Test File" is only the name of the board, and this won't be stored in the array. The "3 3" part specifies the dimensions of the board, yet also won't be read into the array. The only bits I need to read into the array are the characters below these lines.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalStateException {

    int lineCount = 0;
    String[] rowN = null;

    try {

        Scanner boardInput = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        Scanner movesInput = new Scanner(new File(args[1]));

        col = boardInput.nextLine().split("").length; // counts the columns

        while (boardInput.hasNextLine()) { // iterates through board file

            rows++; // counts the rows

        }

        rows -= 2;
        String line = boardInput.nextLine();
        while(boardInput.hasNextLine()){

            if (lineCount > 1){

                 rowN = line.split("");
                 boardArray[lineCount-2] = rowN;
                 line = boardInput.nextLine();
                 lineCount++;


            }



        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(boardArray));


        //playGame();

        boardInput.close();
        movesInput.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

I feel it only helpful if I explain the reasoning behind my attempt. First I managed to find the no.columns simply by reading in one of the lines, and getting its length. Second, I managed to find the number of rows by iterating through the file and counting the number of lines, and then subtracted 2, to account for the previous unwanted lines. With this, I get the dimensions of my array ; rows and col.

The next part I found more tricky. I iterated through the file again, and checked if the variable lineCount is bigger than 1 ( to account for the previous lines). If so, then designated the array **rowN** equal to the different characters of the first row of characters that we want. After this point I got stuck, and have been trying for a while now to solve this problem. Thank you for your time!

Comment: The second line of your board file gives you the dimensions of a char[][] array to hold the game board.  The third and onward lines are the rows of the char[][] array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you try to get the board dimension from the dimensions of the text files, if you could straight read it from said file.
And the way you currently try to do it seems to me like it contains some errors:

```
col = boardInput.nextLine().split("").length;
```

This will give you if you look at the test file 9 columns because the first line in your test file: "Test file" contains 9 characters, but the board is only 3 wide.

Determining the row like you do now will also give problems, because `boardInput.hasNextLine()` won't change until you actually take the next line using `boardInput.nextLine()`, so you essentially have an infinite while loop there.

Fixing this is actually quite easy because the file contains the informations about column and row:

```
String name = boardInput.nextLine(); // Store the name of the board so the next line can be processed.
String[] rowAndCol = boardInput.nextLine().split(" "); // Takes the second line and splits it into its two parts.
// Parse the two Strings to integers(Assuming the first number is the row and the second is the column):
int row = Integer.parseInt(rowAndCol[0]);
int col = Integer.parseInt(rowAndCol[1]);
```

Now with that out of the way it's time to solve the problem you actually asked about. First of all you need to make a 2-dimensional array representing your board and then fill it with the characters each line. Filling the Array is actually pretty easy because you can convert a String to an array of chars with a single function call:

```
char[][] board = new char[row][];
for(int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
    board[r] = boardInput.nextLine().toCharArray();
}
```

An interesting thing to note is that you don't even need to know the number of columns to make a correct array(assuming the file is correctly formatted).